# sorted list of Doubly linked list.

Tags: doubly-linked-list

please help me with the insert method please. i want to insert an int which have a value greater than that int in the doubly linked list. then the new int will replace the greater value from the doubly linked list (i got that working fine). but now i want that greater int to go down the list and be inserted where appropriate.

if i say insert 2 4 6 8 , it will work (result: 2 4 6 8) 
if i then insert 1 (which is smaller than 2)

result will be 1 4 6 8 
               2

the problem is, when i insert lets say 7 (greater than 6, but smaller than 8) i dont know how to go down row and insert where appropriate.

```
enter code here
```

public void insert(int newInt) {
        Cell newCell = new Cell (newInt);

```
  if (this.size() == 0){
      smallest = newCell;
  } 

  for (Cell i = smallest; i != null; i = i.right){

      // if newCell is the larger than all in row, then add it to the end. 
      if (newCell.value > i.value && i.right == null){
          i.right = newCell; 
      }

      // if newCell is smaller than smallest, then add it to smallest and old smallest will go down the list (compare and put it where appropriate). 
      if (newCell.value < smallest.value){
          newCell.below = smallest; 
          newCell.right = smallest.right; 
          smallest.right = null; 
          smallest = newCell; 

      }

      // if newCell is smallest than any element, then replace that cell with newCell, and send that cell to below row
      // do again untill all below rows are sorted. hence this could be a while loop. 
      if (newCell.value > i.value && newCell.value < i.right.value){
          System.out.println("newCell is " + newCell);
          Cell largerRight = i.right; 
          newCell.right = largerRight.right;
          largerRight.right = null; 
          i.right = newCell; 


          temp = smallest.below; 


          while (temp != null){
              System.out.println(temp); 

              for (Cell k = temp; k != null; k = k.right){

                  if (largerRight.value > temp.value && temp.right == null){
                      temp.right = largerRight;
                      temp = null; 
                  }



              }


              temp =temp.below; 
          }

      }

  }










}//end insert
```

Comment: Alisha, it's not a good idea to make such a massive change to questions since they invalidate the answers given to date. The proper way would usually be to ask a fundamentally different question as, well, a different question :-) If you _are_ hell bent on changing this one, I'll delete my answer since it no longer applies.

Comment: i am happy with the answer u have give. i will post a different question rather... but before that, i will try to practise more with the answer you have given. hope i find the answer myself, if not then i will post the other question. again thnx for ur time to answer. really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When inserting into a doubly linked list, you almost always have a first and last pointer. You also have a new node that you want inserted in the list, but as yet without the pointer information.

I'll do this in pseudo-code so you can translate it to whatever language you want (and since it *may* be homework).

First, detect an empty list. If that's the case, just build a new one-element list:

```
if first == NULL:
    newNode->next = NULL  # one element pointing nowhere.
    newNode->prev = NULL
    first = newNode       # first and last are that element.
    last = newNode
    return
```

Otherwise, find the first node greater than the current, that's where you want to insert before:

```
insertPoint = first                              # scan list until end.
while insertPoint != NULL:
    if insertPoint->payload > newNode->payload:  # stop if found one greater.
        break;
    insertPoint = insertPoint->next              # move to next.
```

Now, there are three distinct possibilities here:

1. `insertPoint` is the first node, meaning you have to insert at the front;
2. `insertPoint` is `NULL`, meaning you have to append to the list; or
3. `insertPoint` is a valid node other than the first.

First, handle the two special cases. These are considered special since they change the control information of the list (`first` and `last`), rather than just pointers within the nodes themselves:

```
if insertPoint == first:      # inserting at front.
    newNode->next = first     # new node points forwards to current first
    newNode->prev = NULL      #   and backwards to nowhere.
    first = newNode           # and update first.
    return

if insertPoint = NULL:        # appending to end.
    newNode->next = NULL      # new node points forwards to nowhere
    newNode->prev = last      #   and backwards to current last.
    last = newNode            # and update last.
    return
```

If you've gotten to here, you simply need to insert, knowing that you have a valid current and previous node:

```
newNode->next = insertPoint        # set new node to point to correct nodes.
newNode->prev = insertPoint->prev
insertPoint->prev->next = newNode  # update those nodes to point to new node.
insertPoint->prev = newNode
return
```

Comment: thnx for you time and effort.... and sorry for not putting all this code before, i am still new to stackoverflow... still learning how to ask help...